# ClearCase tutorial for Git users?

Tags: git, version-control, clearcase

I just recently started a job where the primary VCS is ClearCase. Most of my experience is with Git, and I also have a bit of SVN experience from when I first started developing.

I notice there are a lot of resources for ClearCase developers to migrate to Git, but not vice versa.

What are the best resources for me, as a Git dev using ClearCase?

Comment: I wrote the resources http://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1074785/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5550566/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/764219/6309

Comment: But I would *really* like to know what particular environment would justify, in 2017, to use ClearCase. This seems backward. Is it ClearCase UCM? ClearCase multiSite? using dynamic views?

Comment: The company has been using ClearCase for a really long time, like 20+ years. There are plans to migrate to git, but the code base is massive, millions of lines, so it will be an undertaking.

Comment: Git operates at the component level (one component per repo), so the challenge is to chip away from the massive central Vobs the components you want as Git repo. Is the company using dynamic views?

Comment: Yes, we are using dynamic views.

Comment: OK, that is the one feature specific to ClearCase that you won't find in any other VCS. I mention some links above: do they provide you with enough information to start?

Comment: History rewrite is one reason not to use Git in 2017.  Many shops depend upon history remaining static.